# SQL optimization for XML Path

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance, optimization, xml

```
SELECT distinct STUFF(
   (SELECT distinct ',' + hg.CODE
    FROM SP_HD hg
    Inner join Purchase.SP_DT on GOODS_RECEIPT_ID = hg.ID
    WHERE PO_DT_ID = d.PO_DT_ID
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
   ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'') GRN_CODE,
```

The for XML usage is causing me performance issues . Is there any fast alternatives for this ?

Comment: Let's check out the [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/) and other basic things first.

Comment: Not one, but /two/ 'select distinct's in there - Big Red Flag (for me) performance-wise.

Comment: What is this code doing?...string concatenation (aggregation)? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any fast alternatives for this ?

SQL Server now has a native function for string concatenation across rows: [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)